# _ is undefined _.extend(Model.prototype, Events, { but it is in included file

Tags: backbone.js

I have dowloaded backbone.js from http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/, included that file inside script tag and create view in onReady function like http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View
but I always get message **** _ is undefined  _.extend(Model.prototype, Events, {****
but when I look in file _extend is there and path is 100% ok. Did anyone have same behavior ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Backbone is dependent on [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).
Include it first.